# Is it possible to use Inception Model in GANs (DCGAN) using PyTorch(or any other library)?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, gan, inception

*MAIN ISSUE*:
Is it possible to use Inception Model (e.g. v3) for DCGAN using PyTorch(any other library)?

I've tried to find info how it could be implemented but nothing has been found.
It was explained how it works [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html#model-training-and-validation-code) . It seems that it's possible to use it for discriminator if the output is known.

*QUESTIONS*:

- Is it possible to somehow apply the model to the GAN? (in particular for DCGAN) [what should be the labelled outputs?] [how does it implement for generator?]?
- Can be the size of the input images decreased somehow? (it's written that input size of the image should be 299x299). But simple training takes quite a lot of time at images of size 64x64 in GPU processor.

Any hints are welcome.